# Correlating two 3D arrays in Python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have two datasets that I need to correlate in Python. One array is a .mat file and the other is a list of .bin files. From these datasets I have created two 3D arrays with the same extent (120x112x244). While familiar with Python I have not worked with such datasets before, and thus am seeking advice on how to correlate these arrays. I attempted numpy correlate and received:
"ValueError: object too deep for desired array"

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated

Comment: You shouldn't replace your question with another when it's been answered. Other people have be able to read it before reading the answer. You can accept the answer to close the question.

Answer (score 4):

One idea I would try is to flatten the 3D matrix first, then use coorelate -- since coorelate only takes 1D vectors.

http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.correlate.html.

Let's say your two matricies are called `A` and `B`.

```
>>> import numpy
>>> array_a = numpy.ndarray.flatten(A)
>>> array_b = numpy.ndarray.flatten(B)
>>> results = numpy.correlate(array_a, array_b)
```